# MATLAB MEX causes memory loss on GPU

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, cuda, gpgpu, mex

I wrote a mex function and noticed that every time I run it, more and more memory disappears from my GPU, even though I overwrite the previous results every time.
In my attempts to find the source of the problem, I wrote the following code (the file is called `MexMemoryTrack`):

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "gpu/mxGPUArray.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])
{
    mxInitGPU();

    const mxGPUArray * inp=mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
    const mxGPUArray * ms=mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[1]);
    const double * inpPtr=(const double*) mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(inp);
    const double * masksPtr=(const double*) mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(ms);
    mxGPUArray * out=mxGPUCopyFromMxArray(prhs[2]);
    double * outPtr=(double* ) mxGPUGetData(out);
    plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(out);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(inp);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(ms);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(out);
}
```

I run it using:

```
foo=gpuArray.zeros([3 3 10000 18]);
foo2=gpuArray.randn([7 7 10000 20]);
foo3=gpuArray.randn([5 5 18 20]);
dumdum=MexMemoryTrack(foo2,foo3,foo);
```

If I put this code in a loop, all my memory ends up disappearing and I get an "out of memory" error.
It's very simple. I allocate the memory, I destroy the memory I created **except** `plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(out);` which isn't, and shouldn't be destroyed. Since I'm overwriting `dumdum` (the only `lhs` argument), I assume Matlab is smart enough to either overwrite the values, or free them and re-allocate space for `dumdum`.
Using `clear dumdum` doesn't work either (if that was the solution, I'd be worried about how to keep the information returned...).

Am I missing something?

Could the compiler be the source of the problem (Visual Studio 2010)? Maybe it doesn't work well with Matlab (I'm using Matlab 2013a)?

Answer (score 1):

After many google searches, I eventually reached a (possible) solution, found [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/392898/cuda-programming-and-performance/matlab-mex-files-and-loops/post/2783986/#2783986)

according to this, lhs is not overwritten when, so when calling the code more than once, copies of previous results remain in the memory - so maybe `lhs[0]` should be destroyed in the beginning of the code (though first we need to check if there is anything to destroy, as it may not have been allocated yet)

I am unable to verify that this will indeed solve the problem, as I am currently without access to a computer with MATLAB and a graphics card.
Basically, the (possible) problem is that the lhs isn't overwritten, but re-allocated (I am actually not surprised, but I wouldn't have guessed that, since I have a poor understanding of exactly how data is handled by MATLAB).

If anyone happens to test out this theory, please let me know what you find out.

Comment: I'm currently using mexfiles directly written in CUDA language and compiled under Visual Studio 2010 for Matlab 2010a. So, I have no experience of `gpuArray`s. I agree that a possible problem is the "continuos" creation of new arrays. Perhaps you should avoid the use of `mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU`. In a naive approach, could you create the `gpuArray` `dumdum` outside the `for` loop, pass its reference to `MexMemoryTrack` and then equate `lhs[0]` to such a reference?

Comment: I believe I may have tried to do this and failed, but that was before I had enough understanding of how to write a mex file. I will try this again. thank you for the help and advice (and for editing my question)

Answer (score 0):

In a couple of posts

[Memory leak while using gpuArray in parallel computing toolbox 2013a](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76225)

[Matlab 2013a GPU memory leak](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77053)

it was recognized that:

> When calling functions using `gpuArray` data in `MATLAB R2013a`, MATLAB's memory usage can increase. A very large number of GPU function calls might exhaust the available memory, causing an `Out of Memory` or `Java heap space error`.

There is a patch published at this [bug report page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/954239) capable to overcome the problem. This bug has been fixed as of `MATLAB R2013b`.